# Polymer with AngularJS ng-repeat-start ng-repeat-end Firefox issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, angularjs-ng-repeat, polymer

This code doesn't work on Firefox 35.0.1 but works good on Chrome 40.0.2214.111. Error occur only if I import polymer webcomponents.js library to my angular project. Probably it dosen't occure on Chrome because this browser has native support https://www.polymer-project.org/resources/compatibility.html. When I replace ng-repeat-start/end with ng-repeat it works good, but doesn't solve my problem. Test code here http://jsbin.com/pimiji/1/edit?html,js,console,output.

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat-start="t in testList">
        <div ng-click="testFunction(t)">{{t}}</div>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat-end>
        <div ng-click="testFunction(t)">{{t}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular controller

```
.controller("TestCtrl", function TestCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.testList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    $scope.testFunction = function(t) {
        console.log(t);
    };
})
```

Error from Firefox browser console

```
Error: h is undefined
g@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:51:299
I@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:59:195
g@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:51:299
g@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:51:316
g@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:51:316
C/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:50:414
sc/d/</<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:18:4
Me/this.$get</k.prototype.$eval@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:124:246
Me/this.$get</k.prototype.$apply@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:124:460
sc/d/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:17:477
e@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:36:363
sc/d@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:17:1
sc@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:18:179
Gd@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:17:1
@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:248:152
a@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:163:237
gf/c@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js:32:307
invoke@http://raw.githubusercontent.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/master/src/ShadowDOM/wrappers/events.js:423:11
dispatchAtTarget@http://raw.githubusercontent.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/master/src/ShadowDOM/wrappers/events.js:337:12
dispatchEvent@http://raw.githubusercontent.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/master/src/ShadowDOM/wrappers/events.js:306:11
dispatchOriginalEvent@http://raw.githubusercontent.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/master/src/ShadowDOM/wrappers/events.js:238:1
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Seems to be working fine with me in FireFox 35.0.1: http://jsbin.com/naduho/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: You're right. Now I see that it looks like polymer problem with webcomponents.js library. [link](http://jsbin.com/pimiji/1/edit?html,js,console,output)